# Is there any way to fully-populate a table with preset values only on the first execution?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, hql

When hibernate runs for the first time, it automatically creates our tables based on our entities. For example, there's an entity like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
```

And its default values are:

```
1 ------ ok
2 ------ not ok
3 ------ irregular
4 ------ none of the above
```

Is it possible, when hibernate starts, to check if this table is empty and if so, populate this table with these values?

Answer (score 1):

You can use data migration tools, Many of these tools integrate with Spring Boot very nicely. Please check [FlyWay](https://flywaydb.org/).

These tools will help you to initialize your database with default values.

Answer (score 1):

Create a DBInitializer class with @Postconstruct anotation method and then you can initialize the values or populate the values to the database Like:

```
@Service
public class DBInitializer{
private Logger logger = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(DBInitializer.class)
@Autowired
 ProductRepository productRepo;

@PostConstruct
void init(){
logger.info("Starting Database initialization...")
Product product =new Product();
product.setName("blah");
productRepo.save(product);
  }

  }
```

Comment: This @PostConstruct annotation It only works with spring-managed-beans, right?

Comment: Yes it works on spring managed beans.. Actually you need to create a service class that will be used to populate values. I revised the answer there was mistake made by me.